# query without derived table

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0

I have two tables flat and usertoflat I want to fetch all data from flat table with where condition on usertoflat table.

I am using JPA but I didn't found derived table query in jpa below is my native sql query.

```
Table Flat

flat_id | flat_no | status
   1    |   1001  |   1
   2    |   1002  |   1
   3    |   1003  |   1
   4    |   1004  |   1


Table usertoflat

usertoflat_id | Name    | flat_id | status
      1       | ABC     |   1     |   1
      2       | ABC     |   1     |   2
      3       | XYZ     |   2     |   1
      4       | PQR     |   3     |   1


Required output

flat_id | flat_no | Name
   1    |   1001  | ABC
   2    |   1002  | XYZ
   3    |   1003  | PQR
   4    |   1004  |
```

Query with derived table

```
select f.flat_id, f.flat_no, uf.name from flat f left join 
(select * from usertoflat where status  = 1 )
as uf on f.flat_id = uf.flat_id
```

How to achieve the same without using derived table, since I am using JPA and I didn't found derived table in JPA so if I can get the native sql query I will convert the same in JPA query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply make a left join instead of creating a subquery

```
SELECT
    f.flat_id,
    f.flat_no,
    uf.name
FROM flat f
LEFT JOIN usertoflat uf ON  f.flat_id = uf.flat_id AND uf.status = 1;
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e75ceb/1/0)</kbd>

**Or**

```
SELECT
    f.flat_id,
    f.flat_no,
    uf.name
FROM flat f
LEFT JOIN usertoflat uf ON  f.flat_id = uf.flat_id 
WHERE uf.status IS NULL OR uf.status = 1;
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e75ceb/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: I tried with your query but then flat id 4 is not coming since 4 is not present in usertoflat table

Comment: Try now please. Moved `uf.status = 1` from `where` to `ON` clause.

Comment: Second query is working and first query is not working

Comment: Actually the above two queries are same. Both should work. I don't know why the first isn't working in your case :(

Comment: First one is not working because it filter out uf.status is null and pull only where uf.status = 1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need?

```
select f.flat_id, f.flat_no, uf.name from flat f left join 
usertoflat uf on f.flat_id = uf.flat_id and uf.status  = 1
```

Comment: with this query flat_id 4 is not coming in output (and status is there in both table I tried with uf.status)